# Passing parent scope variables to ui-view component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-components

I'm using angular-ui/ui-router and have directives/components with isolate scope defined to be rendered on state change.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('about', {
      url: '/about',
      template: '<about></about>'
    })
    .state('blog', {
      url: '/blog',
      template: '<blog></blog>'
    })
```

My main page is a directive that loads the user with all permissions in its controller

```
app.directive('main', function() {
  return {
    ...
    template: "<div><header></header><div ui-view></div></div>",
    controller: [..., function(...) {
       $scope.user = // $http load user
    }]
);
```

When navigating to different states, I want the user to be passed to all ui-view directives/components. However I can't find a nice way to realize this ***without a `resolve` that would load the user on every state change or using the `$rootScope`***

I'm looking for something similar to the following, where user is the one from the parent scope.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('about', {
      url: '/about',
      template: '<about user="user"></about>'
    })
    .state('blog', {
      url: '/blog',
      template: '<blog user="user"></blog>'
    })
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Where does the client enter the username? Could the `$http` fetch of permissions be refactored into a service?

Answer (score 1):

in the controller, you can assign the user to $rootScope, like `$rootScope.user = sth`, then you can whether add controller for each state url to get the user like `$scope.user= $rootScope.user`, or pass the rootScope user as parameter.

Comment: I guess this is a valid solution (upvoted). However I'm looking into transitioning our Angular 1.x app to Angular 2.x and try to avoid using $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $rootscope in your controller like this

```
$rootScope.user = sth;
```

and you can get user like this

```
$scope.user= $rootScope.user;
```

Comment: As commented on @Stephanie's answer, I don't want to use the $rootScope

Comment: if u don't want to use $rootscope then you can use $broadcast or $emit to propagate data downwards or upwards, as per your need.